# Problem with Linq result

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Hi I have had a problem with some method that should perform action on some IEnumerator object instance, the code sample shows the case:

```
class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] testArray = { "Item1", "Item2" };

            var query = testArray.Select((item, index) => new { index, item });

            Console.WriteLine("Query run 1, {0}", Environment.NewLine);

            foreach (var obj in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", obj);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Query run 2, {0}", Environment.NewLine);

            doAction<object>(query as IEnumerator<object>, obj => Console.WriteLine(obj) );


            Console.WriteLine("Query run 3 ( same as run 1), {0}", Environment.NewLine);

            foreach (var obj in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", obj);
            }

            Object tmp = Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static void doAction<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, Action<T> action)
        {

            if (enumerator == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerator");
            }

            if (action == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
            }


            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                action(enumerator.Current);
            }

        }
    }
```

The output:

```
Query run 1,

{ index = 0, item = Item1 }
{ index = 1, item = Item2 }
Query run2,

Query run 3 ( same as run 1), 

{ index = 0, item = Item1 }
{ index = 1, item = Item2 }
```

Does anyone know what method `doAction` do not take action ?

The real problem is that i need the answer in English language, because my is really bad and i can not explain why this is happening to my mate.

Thanks in advance.

Thnaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you shouldn't be using `IEnumerator<T>` directly, only `IEnumerable<T>`. Basically you're seeing an oddity of the way that the C# compiler implements iterator blocks: there's one type which implements both `IEnumerable<T>` *and* `IEnumerator<T>`. That's unusual in itself, but is done for performance reasons. It's not something you should take advantage of or rely on.

Fundamentally, casting an `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerator<T>` is a bad idea - you *shouldn't* do it. They're different interfaces representing subtly different ideas - the difference between "a sequence which *can* be iterated over" and "something which *is* iterating over a sequence".

If you *really* want to use `IEnumerator<T>` as the parameter type for `doAction` (which would normally be `DoAction`, btw) just call `GetEnumerator()` instead:

```
using (var iterator = query.GetEnumerator())
{
    doAction<object>(iterator, obj => Console.WriteLine(obj) );
}
```

Comment: How could someone make that mistake? When processing the results of a linq query don't use `IEnumerator<T> Interface` which "Supports a simple iteration over a generic collection." Instead use `IEnumerable<T> Interface` which "Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a collection of a specified type."

Comment: Thank You. Not so many words and so much information, great answer.